# Locking excel rows by date - using for work follow up

Tags: excel, vba

I need to lock the row based on past dates. I try to build an Excel macro for job-tracking. For example, I want to ensure that a person can edit today and record their work in more than 1 row (eg. for different projects) today with today's date but cannot edit this record tomorrow.

Here is my macro. Is there anything I can fix or add?

```
Sub ProtectAndDeleteDataValidation()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim belowLastRow As Long
    Dim currentDate As Date
    Dim checkDate As Date
    Dim i As Long
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim countFilledCells As Long
    
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Production Table")
    
    ws.Unprotect Password:="111111"
    
     For Each allowRange In ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges
        allowRange.Delete
    Next allowRange
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set rng = ws.Range("A" & lastRow & ":M" & lastRow)
    countFilledCells = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng)
    If countFilledCells = 13 Then
    
    currentDate = Date
      
    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        If Not IsEmpty(ws.Cells(i, "A").Value) Then
            lastRow = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    
    belowLastRow = i + 1
    aboveLastRow = i - 1
    
    
    checkDate = ws.Cells(lastRow, "N").Value
    
    If checkDate < currentDate Then
     
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
      
        ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="EditRange1", Range:=ws.Range("A" & belowLastRow & ":I1000")
        ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="EditRange2", Range:=ws.Range("K" & belowLastRow & ":M1000")
       
        ws.Range("A2:M" & i).Validation.Delete
      
        ws.Protect Password:="111111"
    Else
    
        ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="EditRange1", Range:=ws.Range("A" & lastRow & ":I1000")
        ws.Protection.AllowEditRanges.Add Title:="EditRange2", Range:=ws.Range("K" & lastRow & ":M1000")
      
        ws.Protect Password:="111111"
    
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Is there any error?

Comment: With this code, I can not obtain what i want to do.